# Get 9 AM of current day in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Can anyone tell me how to get **9AM** of the **current day** in Oracle?

In SQL Server I would do the following:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), '09:00:00')
```

I'm writing a stored procedure that only retrieves data from 9 AM of the same day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select trunc(sysdate) +9/24 from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I went with >   trunc(sysdate)+(9/24)

Answer (score 3):

Just take the current day at midnight and add nine hours

```
trunc(sysdate) + interval '9' hour
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try to get 9AM of the current day in Oracle using the following:**

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate + 1) + 9/24, 'HH')|| 'AM' as "current day 9AM" 
from dual;
```

Comment: This will return a string `'09AM'` or `'09PM'` depending on whether the query is run in the morning or afternoon respectively ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=467e634d7e10cf325be373ce47b50062)). The question is after a `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) data type of the current day at 09:00.

Comment: Thank you for your kind information.    select to_char(trunc(sysdate + 1) + 9/24, 'HH')|| 'AM' as "current day 9AM" 
from dual;

Comment: That still returns a string and not a date and if you are going to do that then you might as well just use a string literal like `SELECT '9AM' AS "current day 9AM" FROM DUAL;` rather than obfuscating what you are doing and trying to fit a call to `SYSDATE` in there that makes it seem like you are using dates when you are generating a fixed string.

Comment: Well, I think only 9 return will be the date format, not 9 AM.
example:
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP)) AS "Date format"
,TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH12 AM') "Date string"
,TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24 AM') "Date 24Hr string"
,TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1) + 9/24,'HH'),'HH')  AS "Date format 24hr"
,TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'FMHH'),'HH') "Date format 12Hr"
 FROM DUAL;

Comment: `TRUNC( SYSDATE + 1 ) + 9/24` will give 09:00 tomorrow and wrapping that in `TO_CHAR( datevalue, 'HH' )` will always return the string `'09'` as the hour will always be 9 - this return value is not a `DATE` data type it is a string and it will be a constant value for whatever value the `SYSDATE` input takes. `'09' || 'AM'` is just concatenating two strings and it will always result in `'09AM'`, which is again a string and not a `DATE` data type. Your answer does not do as is expected and the point you are trying to make in the previous comment appears to be confused and unclear.